# convert from php to vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net

i need this code converted form php to vb.net. Any ideas?

```
    $this->load->library('curl');
    $this->curl->create('http://abc.com');
    $jsonstr = '{"data":
                [{
                    "campaign_id":"5",
                    "owner_id":"0",
                    "status":"unassigned"
                },
                {
                    "campaign_id":"5",
                    "owner_id":"0",
                    "status":"unassigned"
                ]}';

    $this->curl->post(array(
        'insuranceleads' => $jsonstr
    ));
    $result = $this->curl->execute();
    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl is an executable. To use it from .NET, you can fire up a Process object and run it. I believe PHP wraps it, as I do not believe you can consume Curl as a library.